# failling to import urllib.request with python 3.8.3

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to run the below code on my windows10 machine using the cmd line  but the output is a Traceback with a ModuleNotFoundError.
I've written the code with a sublimtext3 editor

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib.request
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')
counts = dict()
for line in fhand: [enter image description here][1]
    words = line.decode().split() 
for word in words: 
    counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1 
print(counts)
```

Comment: Have you checked urllib is installed in python3. You can check via opening python3 console and `import urllib`. If still the error, install it.

Comment: urllib is installed                                                                                                     
 C:\Users\AMANI>python
                                                                                                                            
 Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib

Comment: Ok does python and python3 same?

Comment: i found a solution,  i had another urllib file in the same folder. i just had to delelete it and it's fine.